# .push array method is not working angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

```
app. filter('bygenre', function() {
    var out = [];
    return function(phone , genres) {


    if(genres) {

    angular.forEach(phone, function (value, key) {
         console.log(value.rating);
      console.log(Number(genres.rating))
      if (value.rating & genres.rating){
      if (value.rating == Number (genres.rating))
      {
        //alert("hello");
        console.log("this is value"+ JSON.stringify (value));
        out.push[value];
        console.log("this is out"+ JSON.stringify (out));
      }
    }


    });


    }
    console.log("this is "+ JSON.stringify (out));  
    return out ;
  } 
  });
```

I have this code the  out.push[value]; is not working for me 
[http://plnkr.co/edit/8ArGO1OvT7FHIV1ixSEA?p=preview   Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ArGO1OvT7FHIV1ixSEA?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Array push is a method, so:

`out.push[value]` should be `out.push(value)`.